# What can I do to fix this GPA calculator I'm working on in python

Tags: python

Quick question here, I'm fairly new to python and have to write out a script that pops out the GPA of a given set of grades. Here's the issue, this code works, but in the form gpa('AB'), once it gets more than 2 inputs it goes out of whack, with 'AB' = 3.5 to 'AAB' = 2.33 which is obviously not the case. What can I do to fix this up?

```
def gpa(grade):
    letter = list(grade)
    points = 0
    if 'A' in letter:
        points = points + 4.0
    if 'B' in letter:
        points = points + 3.0
    if 'C' in letter:
        points = points + 2.0
    if 'D' in letter:
        points = points + 1.0
    if 'F' in letter:
        points = points + 0.0
    total = (points)/len(letter)
    return total
```

Comment: Your code only checks whether, say, `A` is in the list, _not_ how many `A`s are in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already had one good answer, I'll supply the unnecessary one-liner:

```
gpas = "FDCBA"
def gpa(grade):
    points = sum( gpas.index(letter) for letter in grade )
    return points/len(grade)

print(gpa('AB')) # output: 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check *each grade* and then add the points for that grade. You can do this with an `if-else` ladder like [j1-lee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67643719/843953) suggests, or you can use a dictionary that maps each letter to its score:

```
def gpa(grades):
    grade_to_point = {"A": 4., "B": 3., "C": 2., "D": 1.}
    total = 0.
    for letter in grades:
        total += grade_to_point.get(letter, 0.) # Get the value from the dict. 0 if letter wasn't found in the dict
    return total / len(grades)
```

If you were so inclined, you could pythonize this by using the `sum()` function and a generator expression.

```
def gpa(grades):
    grade_to_point = {"A": 4., "B": 3., "C": 2., "D": 1.}
    return sum(grade_to_point.get(letter, 0.) for letter in grades) / len(grades)
```